# how to build a react native multi app repository

Tags: mobile, react-native

so I am working on a new project, the codebase will spit out ios and android, but the client wants the codebase to be configurable
so let's say the app sells shoes, the UI and all assets and content will be about shoes, but then he wants to reuse the codebase to make another app that sells 
skateboards

can I pass the params? maybe have them in buddybuild too?
Has anyone ever done this before? any tutorials or help would be appreciated

Comment: You can create an object that has all of the app's default lines. For example `var config = { appName: 'shoe store' }`

Comment: how does that change the appicon in xcode and android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Buddybuild treats each project as a separate application. Our recommendation in this situation is to

- Onboard the app on buddybuild as many time as you want to reuse your codebase
- Tweak your codebase with environment variables using a custom build step

You can find more information about our custom build steps mechanism [on our blog](https://www.buddybuild.com/blog/customize-mobile-build-steps) and in [our docs](https://docs.buddybuild.com/builds/custom_build_steps.html). We also have some documentation about [how to set environment variables](https://docs.buddybuild.com/builds/secrets/environment_variables.html).

Let me know if this helps!